# How to fixPermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION Location Permission Not Granted React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, geolocation, android-permissions

I use geolocation for the react native application that I made, but the location permissions are not allowed to pop up.

I have added permissions on Android Manifest and tried to use the library but the results are the same

```
  async componentDidMount() {

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

      await request_device_location_runtime_permission()

    }

    this.getLongLat = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        })
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 100, distanceFilter: 10 },
    )

  }
```

I expect that the permissions location can be active, and latitude and longitude the current location can be displayed

Comment: Where are the questions about permissions?

Comment: Yes about permissions where location permissions don't work

Comment: I mean, when you look at the code, where do you ask for permissions?

Comment: [link]https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VFZKlJMf-KA/XTlX93nC4nI/AAAAAAAAHbo/WoqeWJCzJvsvZwTLPjdFA2HzToJz9lDJwCLcBGAs/s0/Screen%2BShot%2B2019-07-25%2Bat%2B14.18.36.png[link] . thats the picture

Comment: As you can see from your picture, there is no agreement of permissions.

Comment: @hongdevelop no the pop up not showing, here my full code: https://pastebin.com/L040uriE

Comment: Yes, that's the problem the pop up immediately appears like that, even though when I tried it at the expo it could

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expo-permissions`

you can run `expo install expo-permissions`

You should obtain both of the following privileges:

> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: 'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: 'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'

**Example**

```js
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

    const permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (permission.status !== "granted") {
      const newPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

      if (newPermission.status === "granted") {
          console.log("Permissions granted");
       }else {
         console.log("newPermission not granted");
      }

}else{
 console.log("Permissions granted");
}
```

Comment: Don't you ask me about permission?

Comment: Ya but not working. I don't know why, because I run in Expo work.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: location not granted

Comment: There is no such log in the code I wrote in the answer. Did you write the code for the answer?

Comment: Yes I was tried,  I was tried using library react-permission

Comment: If you are using Expo, do not use react-permission, but use the built-in module, expo-permission.

Comment: I was used react native

Comment: Did you migrate to Expo?